# angular2, importing extern directive not working

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-directives

I was trying to make use of the angular2-resizing-cropping-image (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-resizing-cropping-image) in my angular2 project. I started it blank and ran the following command:

```
npm install angular2-resizing-cropping-image
```

Within the npm nodes the package is visible but when i use the following code in my app.module.ts:

[image]

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { lyResizingCroppingImagesModule } from "angular2-resizing-cropping-image";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    lyResizingCroppingImagesModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR in C:/Users/rwormsbecher/angular/angular-image-crop/src/app/app.module.ts (5,48): Cannot find module 'angular2-resizing-cropping-image'.)
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I tried to find some info online what could be the problem but didn't find anything, but i guess its not loading the package or something.

any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have it in your node-module folder?

Comment: yes it shows in the node modules. I included an image in the original post.